# Issue with apex:inpufield( API v31)

Tags: apex, visualforce, issue

Try to replicate this issue

Create a `opportunity` and add few `opportunity contact role` records.

Now create below VF page and controller

```
public class TestPageCtrl1 {

    public List<OpportunityContactRole> lstOppContactRole {get;set;}
    public map<Id, Contact> mapContactIdToContact {get;set;}
    public TestPageCtrl1(){
        mapContactIdToContact = new map<Id, Contact>();
        lstOppContactRole = [Select Id, ContactId, OpportunityId, IsPrimary, Role FROM OpportunityContactRole Where OpportunityId = '00628000003Phn2']; 
        fetchContactAddress();
    }
    public void fetchContactAddress(){
        set<Id> setContactId = new set<Id>();
        for(OpportunityContactRole objContactRole: lstOppContactRole)
        {
            if(objContactRole.ContactId != null)
                setContactId.add(objContactRole.ContactId);
        }
        mapContactIdToContact = new map<Id, Contact>([SELECT MailingStreet, MailingCity,  OtherStreet, OtherCity FROM Contact WHERE Id IN: setContactId]);
    }
}
```

**Where OpportunityId = '00628000003Phn2' replcace id with your opportunity id**

**VF page.**

```
<apex:page controller="TestPageCtrl1">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputPanel id="tablePanel">
      <table cellspacing="0"  cellpadding="2" style="width:50%;">
         <tr>
            <th>Primary</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Mailling Address</th>
            <th>Other Address</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="out" name="primary" checked="true" onclick= "changeValue(this);" />
            </td>
            <td>No Primary Partner</td>
         </tr>
         <apex:repeat value="{!lstOppContactRole}" var="oppContactRole">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input value="{!oppContactRole.IsPrimary}" type="radio" id="out" name="primary" onclick= "changeValue(this);"/>
                  <apex:InputCheckBox value="{!oppContactRole.IsPrimary}" styleclass="temp" style="display:none !important;"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!oppContactRole.ContactId}" required="false" >
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!fetchContactAddress}" reRender="tablePanel" status="counterStatus" />
                  </apex:inputField>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!oppContactRole.Role}"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!oppContactRole.ContactId != null}">
                   <!--<apex:variable var="contactId" value="{!oppContactRole.contactId}" />-->
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:outputLabel value="Mailing Street"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputField value="{!mapContactIdToContact[oppContactRole.contactId].MailingStreet}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:outputLabel value="Mailing City"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputField value="{!mapContactIdToContact[oppContactRole.contactId].MailingCity}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </apex:repeat>
      </table>
   </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Now try to change the Contact Role's contactId that will fire the `fetchContactAddress` method. and you will get Error

> Map key 00328000007oAqnAAE not found in map.

---

**I found the workaround for this. Need to update the version or use apex:variable to store `oppContactRole.contactId` and use in map so this will work.**

```
<apex:variable var="contactId" value="{!oppContactRole.contactId}" /> 

<apex:inputField value="{!mapContactIdToContact[contactId].MailingStreet}" />
```

---

Just wanted to know why this is not working with **API v31**. Looks like it is a bug.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: So are you saying that without change it works in v34 but not in v31?

Comment: Yes @Eric I just updated the v31 to v32 it works without any issue

Comment: Why don't you answer yourself?since you mentioned answer ,put it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug.

Solution for this issue. Just update the **API v31 to v32** not tested with v33 etc.

else

Use 
`<apex:variable>` to store `oppContactRole.contactId` and use in map so this will work.

like below

```
<apex:variable var="contactId" value="{!oppContactRole.contactId}" /> 

<apex:inputField value="{!mapContactIdToContact[contactId].MailingStreet}" />
```

This will solve above issue.

Comment: Many upvotes for you. I've run into a few issues especially around nested repeats on Map(s) where setting an apex:variable resolves everything.

Comment: was this by any chance listed in Known Issues?

Comment: not sure it is listed in Known Issues or not?